# How to use Page_Load function in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Previously in `aspx` we have

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

function which handled all page load events. But I do not know how this can be used in `MVC`.
Can someone please help !!!

Answer (score 3):

`ASP.NET MVC` doesn't work on events like `ASP.Net`. There is no `PageLoad Event`. Your controller action methods correspond to requests or view sent to the server. You need to build the equivalent control in `HTML`, and then use a `FORM` to `HttpPost` the data to the server, where it is handled by a controller method. Similarly `HttpGet` is used to get data using controller method.

[I suggest you this link to get started with MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

Comment: Actually i have a list which is updated every time when the page is refresh,